Is there a way to ask user a question and wait for answer?
What I have is a script in Text Editor. I need to ask user confirmation before continue of processing, e.g.:
while True:
    some_processing();
    if showYesNoPopup("Continue?") == 'no':
        break

Do this possible in Blender?

Yes, it is possible to ask the user for confirmation in blender and wait for their response. Using the bpy module to create a simple operator.
class ConfirmContinueOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.confirm_continue"
    bl_label = "Continue Processing?"

    def execute(self, context):
        # This is called when the user clicks "OK"
        context.scene.confirm_result = True
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        # This is called when the user clicks "Cancel"
        context.scene.confirm_result = False
        return {'CANCELLED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text="Do you want to continue?")

def show_yes_no_popup():
    bpy.ops.wm.confirm_continue('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
    return bpy.context.scene.confirm_result

# Register the operator
bpy.utils.register_class(ConfirmContinueOperator)

# Add a property to store the user's response
bpy.types.Scene.confirm_result = bpy.props.BoolProperty(default=False)

# Example loop that asks for confirmation
continue_processing = True

while continue_processing:
    # Your processing code here
    print("Processing...")

    # Ask user if they want to continue
    continue_processing = show_yes_no_popup()

    if not continue_processing:
        print("Processing stopped by user.")

The loop uses continue_processing to control whether it continually runs. The variable is set by the results of the show_yes_no_popup().
I'm sure this should answer your comment pasted below, where as long as the continue_processing is true it will keep running. If the inverse is applied, the loop exits.
You may just need to adapt the script for your environment.

Well, it shows dialog "Continue Processing?" with buttons "Cancel" and "Ok". It prints: register_class(...):
Info: Registering operator class: 'ConfirmContinueOperator', bl_idname 'wm.confirm_continue' has been registered before, unregistering previous
Processing...
Processing stopped by user.
Info: Continuing processing...
Looks the loop doesn't work.

If I'm pressing "Ok" it should print "Processing..." and show dialog again and again. And the loop should stop only if I press "Cancel".

im re-editing post to try solve problem.
